# Audio/Video not supported React Native ios webview

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-webview

I'm working on a live video session app. I have used the BigBlueButton API to develop the web version, which is working properly on the web. I'm trying to use that web app URL in my react native app using react-native-webview. In iOS app, I'm able to join the session but while enabling video I'm getting error message as follows

```
**Audio/Video not supported**
At this time audio and video not supported on chrome for ios. We recommend using Safari iOS.
```

When I'm setting userAgent as "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/604.3.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Version/12.0.1 Mobile Safari/604.3.5".

And when I'm setting userAgent as "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/83.0.4103.88 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" I'm getting following error.

```
On iOS please use Safari for full support.
```

When I'm removing the userAgent it showing the error like

```
It looks like you're using a browser that is not supported. Please use either Chrome or Firefox for full support.
```

[image: At this time audio and video not supported on chrome for ios. We recommend using Safari iOS.]
[image: On iOS please use Safari for full support.]
[image: It looks like you're using a browser that is not supported. Please use either Chrome or Firefox for full support.]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to remove all of these user agents? on IOS it uses safari by default.

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar After removing user agent I'm getting "It looks like you're using a browser that is not supported. Please use either Chrome or Firefox for full support.".

Comment: @SaikatKundu are you able to find any solution regarding this ?